# Bluetooth LE advertising stops when unlocking phone

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

My Android phone is advertising via Bluetooth LE. I connect to the device with my Chrome Browser using Web Bluetooth. But as soon as I unlock my phone, it lose connection and gets disconnected.
I already tried another phone but the same happened.
I also can't find anything in the log which would give me a hint what could cause this.

Log:

```
06-22 14:56:48.639 3524-15939/? D/sensorhub: sensorhub_algo_query(): algo: 1
06-22 14:56:48.645 3524-15936/? D/sensorhub: sensorhub_algo_query(): algo: 2
06-22 14:56:48.676 2285-2328/? V/KeyguardServiceDelegate: onScreenTurnedOn(showListener = com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager$2@b42713f)
06-22 14:56:48.677 253-253/? D/SurfaceFlinger: Set power mode=1, type=0 flinger=0xb7349df8
06-22 14:56:48.677 253-253/? D/qdhwcomposer: hwc_setPowerMode: Setting mode 1 on display: 0
06-22 14:56:48.677 253-253/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
06-22 14:56:48.677 253-253/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node
06-22 14:56:48.677 2285-2325/? I/DisplayManagerService: Display device changed state: "Built-in Screen", DOZE
06-22 14:56:48.685 2285-15926/? V/KeyguardServiceDelegate: **** SHOWN CALLED ****
06-22 14:56:48.705 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:48.735 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual true
06-22 14:56:48.735 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual true
06-22 14:56:48.736 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.736 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.736 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.736 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.736 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.736 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.736 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.736 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.736 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.736 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual true
06-22 14:56:48.737 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual true
06-22 14:56:48.737 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.737 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.737 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.737 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.738 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.738 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.738 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.738 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.738 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:48.785 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:48.805 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:48.907 253-775/? I/qdhwcomposer: handle_blank_event: dpy:0 panel power state: 1
06-22 14:56:48.907 253-253/? D/qdhwcomposer: hwc_setPowerMode: Done setting mode 1 on display 0
06-22 14:56:48.907 253-775/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
06-22 14:56:48.907 253-775/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node
06-22 14:56:48.907 2285-3447/? D/SurfaceControl: Excessive delay in setPowerMode(): 230ms
06-22 14:56:49.027 2285-3447/? D/LightsService: Excessive delay setting light: 119ms
06-22 14:56:49.029 2285-2328/? V/KeyguardServiceDelegate: onScreenTurnedOn()
06-22 14:56:50.901 3464-3464/? D/PhoneStatusBar: disable: < expand icons* alerts system_info* back HOME RECENT clock SEARCH  quick_settings >
06-22 14:56:50.901 3464-3464/? D/StatusBarKeyguardViewManager: requestUnlock collapse=true
06-22 14:56:50.903 3464-3464/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: keyguardDone(true, true)
06-22 14:56:50.904 3464-3464/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: handleKeyguardDone(true, true)
06-22 14:56:50.904 3464-3464/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: in handleHide(), mShowing = true mOccluded = false  mHideAnimationRun = false
06-22 14:56:50.904 3464-3464/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: Call PhoneWindowManager's keyguardGoingAway, expect PhoneWindowManager to call startKeyguardExitAnimation
06-22 14:56:50.925 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:50.931 21755-14849/? V/ConnectivityManager: isActiveNetworkMetered() returns:false
06-22 14:56:50.942 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:50.951 3464-3464/? D/KeyguardViewMediator: handleStartKeyguardExitAnimation(324192136, 400)
06-22 14:56:50.953 3464-3464/? D/PhoneStatusBar: disable: < expand icons alerts system_info back HOME RECENT clock SEARCH quick_settings>
06-22 14:56:50.960 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:50.974 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:50.992 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:50.993 2285-9724/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@18bdf5b attribute=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@1fe03f8, token = android.os.BinderProxy@144d6a7
06-22 14:56:50.998 4332-4332/? E/ChimeraRcvrProxy: Can't find Chimera receiver impl class com.google.android.gms.auth.setup.devicesignals.LockScreenChimeraReceiver, dropping broadcast
06-22 14:56:51.007 3464-3464/? D/PhoneStatusBar: disable: < expand icons alerts system_info back home* recent* clock search* quick_settings >
06-22 14:56:51.009 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:51.025 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:51.028 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual true
06-22 14:56:51.028 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual true
06-22 14:56:51.028 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.028 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.028 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.028 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.028 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.028 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.028 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual true
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual true
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.029 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.037 10280-10280/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1221 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:581 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:581 com.motorola.settings.notification.HiddenListenerSettingsReceiver.onReceive:35 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2743 
06-22 14:56:51.040 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:51.045 2285-2296/? I/PowerManagerService: Waking up from dozing (uid 10031)...
06-22 14:56:51.048 2285-5004/? I/DreamManagerService: Leaving dreamland.
06-22 14:56:51.053 2285-2325/? I/DisplayManagerService: Display device changed state: "Built-in Screen", ON
06-22 14:56:51.053 2285-2322/? I/DreamController: Stopping dream: name=ComponentInfo{com.motorola.motodisplay/com.motorola.motodisplay.DozeService}, isTest=false, canDoze=true, userId=0
06-22 14:56:51.055 2285-2285/? V/KeyguardServiceDelegate: onStartedWakingUp()
06-22 14:56:51.065 253-253/? D/SurfaceFlinger: Set power mode=2, type=0 flinger=0xb7349df8
06-22 14:56:51.065 253-253/? D/qdhwcomposer: hwc_setPowerMode: Setting mode 2 on display: 0
06-22 14:56:51.065 253-253/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
06-22 14:56:51.065 253-253/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node
06-22 14:56:51.067 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:51.073 253-253/? D/qdhwcomposer: hwc_setPowerMode: Done setting mode 2 on display 0
06-22 14:56:51.075 253-775/? I/qdhwcomposer: handle_blank_event: dpy:0 panel power state: 1
06-22 14:56:51.075 253-775/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
06-22 14:56:51.075 253-775/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node
06-22 14:56:51.082 22061-22086/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8c4ea18
06-22 14:56:51.087 2285-2285/? V/NotificationListeners: disabling notification listener for user 0: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.stream.NotificationCollectorService}
06-22 14:56:51.090 2285-2285/? V/NotificationListeners: disabling notification listener for user 0: ComponentInfo{com.motorola.motodisplay/com.motorola.motodisplay.MDNotificationListenerService}
06-22 14:56:51.093 2285-2285/? V/NotificationListeners: enabling notification listener for user 0: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.stream.NotificationCollectorService}
06-22 14:56:51.095 2285-2325/? I/WindowManager: window type TYPE_AOD_DREAM:
06-22 14:56:51.100 280-2986/? D/audio_hw_primary: adev_set_parameters: enter: screen_state=on
06-22 14:56:51.100 280-2986/? V/msm8916_platform: platform_set_parameters: enter: - screen_state=on
06-22 14:56:51.101 280-2986/? V/msm8916_platform: platform_set_parameters: exit with code(0)
06-22 14:56:51.101 280-2986/? D/audio_hw_extn: audio_extn_set_anc_parameters: anc_enabled:0
06-22 14:56:51.101 280-2986/? E/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_set_parameters: str_params NULL
06-22 14:56:51.101 280-2986/? E/bt_a2dp_hw: adev_set_parameters: ERROR: set param called even when stream out is null
06-22 14:56:51.116 3464-3758/? D/MotoNetwCtrlr: onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
06-22 14:56:51.116 3464-3758/? I/MotoNetwCtrlr.MotoWifiSignalCtrlr: handleBroadcast: Entered: Intent=Intent { act=android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } Action=android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED
06-22 14:56:51.118 2285-3411/? E/native: do suspend false
06-22 14:56:51.167 2285-3411/? D/WifiConfigStore: No blacklist allowed without epno enabled
06-22 14:56:51.200 21755-25779/? V/ConnectivityManager: isActiveNetworkMetered() returns:false
06-22 14:56:51.357 4110-4110/? D/MD.FrameworkProxyServic: should disconnect Application ? true
06-22 14:56:51.366 22061-22061/? D/ModalityManager: removeMovementListener(), package: com.motorola.motodisplay
06-22 14:56:51.367 3524-3540/? D/SLPC: reg_modalities(): 2, 150000, 1000
06-22 14:56:51.367 3524-3540/? D/SLPC: reg_modalities(): 2
06-22 14:56:51.367 3524-3540/? D/sensorhub: sensorhub_algo_req(): algo: 0, active_parts: 2, num_parts: 6, req_len: 28, bytes: 31
06-22 14:56:51.367 3524-3540/? D/sensorhub: sensorhub_algo_req(): algos: 56
06-22 14:56:51.371 22061-22061/? D/ModalityManager: removeOrientationListener(), package: com.motorola.motodisplay
06-22 14:56:51.376 3524-15933/? D/SLPC: unreg_orientations(): 65535
06-22 14:56:51.376 3524-15933/? D/sensorhub: sensorhub_algo_req(): algo: 1, active_parts: 0, num_parts: 4, req_len: 20, bytes: 23
06-22 14:56:51.376 3524-15933/? D/sensorhub: sensorhub_algo_req(): algos: 40
06-22 14:56:51.380 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
06-22 14:56:51.380 22061-22061/? D/ModalityManager: removeStowedListener(), package: com.motorola.motodisplay
06-22 14:56:51.381 3524-15930/? D/SLPC: unreg_stowed(): 65535
06-22 14:56:51.382 3524-15930/? D/sensorhub: sensorhub_algo_req(): algo: 2, active_parts: 0, num_parts: 3, req_len: 16, bytes: 19
06-22 14:56:51.382 3524-15930/? D/sensorhub: sensorhub_algo_req(): algos: 8
06-22 14:56:51.383 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-22 14:56:51.385 1810-1892/? D/BtGatt.GattService: registerClient() - UUID=ce0f83ed-4ed3-21dd-2311-883d91b4c731
06-22 14:56:51.386 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientRegistered() - UUID=ce0f83ed-4ed3-21dd-2311-883d91b4c731, clientIf=7
06-22 14:56:51.387 4332-4343/? D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
06-22 14:56:51.387 1810-1888/? D/BtGatt.GattService: start scan with filters
06-22 14:56:51.390 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: handling starting scan
06-22 14:56:51.398 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterEnableDisabled() - clientIf=7, status=0, action=1
06-22 14:56:51.398 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 7 status - 0
06-22 14:56:51.398 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureFilterParamter 500 10000 1 0
06-22 14:56:51.409 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=7, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=15
06-22 14:56:51.409 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 7 status - 0
06-22 14:56:51.409 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=1
06-22 14:56:51.409 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=2 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=-2147483648
06-22 14:56:51.409 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams - scanInterval = 8000configureRegularScanParams - scanWindow = 8000
06-22 14:56:51.410 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanParamSetupCompleted : 0
06-22 14:56:51.411 4332-15226/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerActiveIntervalImpl]addNewAppInterval: already contained:appKey=bhn@bb9b632b,appInterval=bhl@deb8eed,record=key=(com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, 10043, account#2028187816#, com.google.android.apps.gsa.extradex.kato.GmsContextManagerClientHelper, a829c33e-bd3a-2817-281c-82bd73c82c8), t=1498119069872, name=USER_LOCATION, lifetime=(WHILE_APP_RUNNING), production=null, retention=null, dispatch=(IMMEDIATE), consumer=(bjg@2182c3a1-2819038291)
06-22 14:56:51.442 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual true
06-22 14:56:51.442 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual true
06-22 14:56:51.442 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.442 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.442 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.442 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.442 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.442 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.442 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.442 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.442 3464-3464/? V/QSTileView: setDual false
06-22 14:56:51.468 3464-3804/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8e90290
06-22 14:56:51.557 2285-2294/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 54779(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 15(1220KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 22MB/33MB, paused 2.295ms total 140ms
06-22 14:56:52.084 15197-15197/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
06-22 14:56:52.085 15197-15197/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
06-22 14:56:52.874 21755-12407/? V/ConnectivityManager: isActiveNetworkMetered() returns:false
06-22 14:56:53.404 5798-5815/? E/MC_LineReader: Error opening /sys/class/power_supply/bms/resistance
                                            java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/power_supply/bms/resistance: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
                                                at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader.<init>(LineReader.java:20)
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader$1.<init>(LineReader.java:53)
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader.firstLineReader(LineReader.java:53)
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.util.BatteryUtils.getBatteryResistance(BatteryUtils.java:130)
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.action.BatteryLevelAction.onReceiveImpl(BatteryLevelAction.java:42)
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.util.BackgroundReceiver$1.run(BackgroundReceiver.java:14)
                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                             Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
                                                at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66) 
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader.<init>(LineReader.java:20) 
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader$1.<init>(LineReader.java:53) 
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.util.LineReader.firstLineReader(LineReader.java:53) 
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.util.BatteryUtils.getBatteryResistance(BatteryUtils.java:130) 
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.action.BatteryLevelAction.onReceiveImpl(BatteryLevelAction.java:42) 
                                                at com.motorola.motocare.util.BackgroundReceiver$1.run(BackgroundReceiver.java:14) 
                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
06-22 14:56:53.407 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
06-22 14:56:53.409 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-22 14:56:53.409 1810-1892/? D/BtGatt.GattService: stopScan() - queue size =1
06-22 14:56:53.410 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: stop scan
06-22 14:56:53.414 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=7, status=0, action=1, availableSpace=16
06-22 14:56:53.414 1810-1822/? D/BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=7
06-22 14:56:53.415 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 7 status - 0
06-22 14:56:53.415 1810-1884/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=3 connected=0 conn_id=3 reason=0x0016
06-22 14:56:53.415 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0
06-22 14:56:53.415 1810-1884/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=4 connected=0 conn_id=4 reason=0x0016
06-22 14:56:53.415 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=2
06-22 14:56:53.415 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped
06-22 14:56:53.415 1810-1884/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=6 connected=0 conn_id=6 reason=0x0016
06-22 14:56:53.415 1810-1884/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=7 connected=0 conn_id=7 reason=0x0016
06-22 14:56:53.415 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: server onConnected() connId=5, address=01:2C:82:BA:2C:23, connected=false
06-22 14:56:53.416 910-1244/com.my.app D/BluetoothGattServer: onServerConnectionState() - status=0 serverIf=5 device=01:2C:82:BA:2C:23
06-22 14:56:53.416 910-1244/com.my.app V/BluetoothServiceXIX: Disconnected from device: 01:2C:82:BA:2C:23
06-22 14:56:53.422 1810-15220/? D/BluetoothMetrics: btclass0
06-22 14:56:53.423 1810-15220/? E/BluetoothMetrics: CheckinEvent exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
06-22 14:56:53.460 1810-1881/? W/bt_hci: filter_incoming_event command complete event with no matching command. opcode: 0x0.
06-22 14:56:53.562 4110-4119/? W/JavaBinder: BinderProxy is being destroyed but the application did not call unlinkToDeath to unlink all of its death recipients beforehand.  Releasing leaked death recipient: com.motorola.motodisplay.env.FrameworkProxyService$1
06-22 14:56:53.563 1810-1884/? I/bt_btm_sec: btm_sec_disconnected clearing pending flag handle:7 reason:22
06-22 14:56:53.563 1810-1884/? W/bt_l2cap: L2CA_SetDesireRole() new:x1, disallow_switch:0
06-22 14:56:53.564 1810-1877/? E/BluetoothRemoteDevices: aclStateChangeCallback: Device is NULL
06-22 14:56:53.585 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
06-22 14:56:53.588 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-22 14:56:53.591 1810-1892/? D/BtGatt.GattService: registerClient() - UUID=cd5f32ba-c169-4d4a-9de6-c82917b52d80
06-22 14:56:53.591 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientRegistered() - UUID=cd5f32ba-c169-4d4a-9de6-c82917b52d80, clientIf=7
06-22 14:56:53.591 4332-20025/? D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
06-22 14:56:53.593 1810-1822/? D/BtGatt.GattService: start scan with filters
06-22 14:56:53.595 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: handling starting scan
06-22 14:56:53.599 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterEnableDisabled() - clientIf=7, status=0, action=1
06-22 14:56:53.599 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 7 status - 0
06-22 14:56:53.599 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureFilterParamter 500 10000 1 0
06-22 14:56:53.600 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=7, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=15
06-22 14:56:53.600 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 7 status - 0
06-22 14:56:53.600 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=1
06-22 14:56:53.600 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=2 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=-2147483648
06-22 14:56:53.600 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams - scanInterval = 8000configureRegularScanParams - scanWindow = 8000
06-22 14:56:53.603 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanParamSetupCompleted : 0
06-22 14:56:53.622 2285-3380/? V/AlarmManager: sending alarm {6298f7d type 3 *alarm*:com.google.android.clockwork.stream.RANK}
06-22 14:56:53.623 2285-2285/? V/AlarmManager: done {6298f7d, *alarm*:com.google.android.clockwork.stream.RANK} [1ms]
06-22 14:56:55.605 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
06-22 14:56:55.606 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-22 14:56:55.606 1810-1892/? D/BtGatt.GattService: stopScan() - queue size =1
06-22 14:56:55.607 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: stop scan
06-22 14:56:55.609 1810-1822/? D/BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=7
06-22 14:56:55.622 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=7, status=0, action=1, availableSpace=16
06-22 14:56:55.622 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 7 status - 0
06-22 14:56:55.622 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0
06-22 14:56:55.622 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=2
06-22 14:56:55.622 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped
06-22 14:56:55.777 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
06-22 14:56:55.780 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-22 14:56:55.784 1810-1822/? D/BtGatt.GattService: registerClient() - UUID=785b4628-5563-46d7-b76a-fda5e828bbb8
06-22 14:56:55.784 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientRegistered() - UUID=785b4628-5563-46d7-b76a-fda5e828bbb8, clientIf=7
06-22 14:56:55.784 4332-4452/? D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
06-22 14:56:55.785 1810-1888/? D/BtGatt.GattService: start scan with filters
06-22 14:56:55.787 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: handling starting scan
06-22 14:56:55.792 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterEnableDisabled() - clientIf=7, status=0, action=1
06-22 14:56:55.792 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 7 status - 0
06-22 14:56:55.792 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureFilterParamter 500 10000 1 0
06-22 14:56:55.794 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=7, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=15
06-22 14:56:55.794 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 7 status - 0
06-22 14:56:55.794 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=1
06-22 14:56:55.794 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=2 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=-2147483648
06-22 14:56:55.794 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams - scanInterval = 8000configureRegularScanParams - scanWindow = 8000
06-22 14:56:55.797 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanParamSetupCompleted : 0
06-22 14:56:57.105 15276-15276/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
06-22 14:56:57.112 15276-15276/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
06-22 14:56:57.396 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
06-22 14:56:57.398 4332-6722/? D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-22 14:56:57.399 1810-1916/? D/BtGatt.GattService: stopScan() - queue size =1
06-22 14:56:57.400 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: stop scan
06-22 14:56:57.408 1810-1820/? D/BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=7
06-22 14:56:57.410 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=7, status=0, action=1, availableSpace=16
06-22 14:56:57.410 1810-1877/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 7 status - 0
06-22 14:56:57.410 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0
06-22 14:56:57.410 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=2
06-22 14:56:57.410 1810-1880/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped
```

Log also availabe on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/cnvgw8es).

Comment: Please post your log in the question, eventhough it is long. It is better to have it all in the same place, as external references might be lost in the future.

Comment: @Luuklag I just added the Log here.

Comment: What device are the logs from? You can enable more Chrome logs using these instructions https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs . What are you serving on the peripheral device? Web Bluetooth works with GATT, are you running a GATT server? Try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral